# Why the author has taken SD $8$ and $ 7$ as $σ$ and not S

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

An examination was given to two classes consisting of $40$ and $50$ students, respectively. In the first class, the mean grade was $74$ with a standard deviation of $8$, while in the second class the mean grade was $78$ with a standard deviation of $7$. Is there a significant difference between the performance of the two classes at a level of significance of $(a)$ $0.05$, $(b)$  $0.0$,  $(c)$ What is the P value of the test?

[Please check the solution here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=iK-wOEIZ_DIC&pg=SA10-PA20&lpg=SA10-PA20&dq=An%20examination%20was%20given%20to%20two%20classes%20consisting%20of%2040%20and%2050%20students,%20respectively.%20In%20the%20first%20class%20the%20mean%20grade%20was%2074%20with%20a%20standard%20deviation%20of%208,%20while%20in%20the%20second%20class%20the%20mean%20grade%20was%2078%20with%20a%20standard%20deviation%20of%207.%20Is%20there%20a%20significant%20difference%20between%20the%20performance%20of%20the%20two%20classes%20at%20a%20level%20of%20significance%20of%20(a)%200.05,%20(b)%200.01?%20(c)%20What%20is%20the%20P%20value%20of%20the%20test?&source=bl&ots=Pzqn7OGMTk&sig=ACfU3U0nibQXBkm_GaAYpNgBA8Zems4GUA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxw4OWxYniAhVHvo8KHZQYCWIQ6AEwB3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=An%20examination%20was%20given%20to%20two%20classes%20consisting%20of%2040%20and%2050%20students%2C%20respectively.%20In%20the%20first%20class%20the%20mean%20grade%20was%2074%20with%20a%20standard%20deviation%20of%208%2C%20while%20in%20the%20second%20class%20the%20mean%20grade%20was%2078%20with%20a%20standard%20deviation%20of%207.%20Is%20there%20a%20significant%20difference%20between%20the%20performance%20of%20the%20two%20classes%20at%20a%20level%20of%20significance%20of%20(a)%200.05%2C%20(b)%200.01%3F%20(c)%20What%20is%20the%20P%20value%20of%20the%20test%3F&f=false)

My question is why $8$ and $7$ have been taken as $σ$, not S if $78$ and $74$ are taken as $x̅$

Comment: Probably because sample sizes are large and so someone is doing a z test instead of a t test. // It is hard for me to figure out how to use the link of view anything relevant.

Comment: The link has the solution done by Author Q 10.17